How to get rid of ucrt under Windows platform completely?
I'm currently writing a simple C runtime under Windows platform to learn better how the compiler/linker works.
The demo project is here: MarsCRT
I'm currently working on strlen(). This function looks like this:
// file: MarsString.c
size_t strlen(char* Char)
{
    size_t Length = 0;
    for(;Char[Length]; Length ++);
    return Length;
}

But when I compile the project
cl /c /GS- ./src/MarsEntry.c ./src/MarsIO.c ./src/MarsMalloc.c ./src/MarsPrintf.c ./src/MarsString.c

...plenty of warnings...
C:\Users\z\Project\Github\dev\marscrt\src\MarsCRT.h(41): error C2371: 'strlen': redefinition; different basic types
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\string.h(215): note: see declaration of 'strlen'
...

It seems that I didn't get rid of the default ucrt correctly.
I check the cl.exe /help but did not find the answer I expected.
So I wonder how to compile the project without ucrt?
I have tried adding /X in the cl.exe as flag, but the project cannot even find <Windows.h>. I also tried the /MD and /MT compiler flags but none of them work as I expected.
Actually I can just add the prefix like mars_strlen() to bypass the ucrt redefinition, but that's not what I want.

Don't name your function the same as the standard function? Don't include the standard <string.h> header file? Make sure your declaration match the one of the standard strlen function?

Only include <Windows.h>

why does this happen? I didn't include any standard header in the project, it shouldn't find the definition of strlen

Is switching to gcc/mingw an option? gcc -freestanding -nostdlib -nolibc ought to nuke all of it. I'm not sure if MSVC has similar options.

You did NOT include it, but other header file will! Do you check ALL header file that you included?  include every #include in <Windows.h> and follow up

Yes, i've checked all the Mars*.c/h file and Windows.h and pretty sure I didn't include <string.h> in my project.

The parameter type should be const char *.

still not work:(

Per the (draft) C11 standard, strlen() is a reserved identifier:

7.1.3 Reserved identifiers

Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and optionally declares or defines identifiers
listed in its associated future library directions subclause and
identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use
as file scope identifiers.

.
.
.

No other identifiers are reserved. If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.


Note that the strlen() identifier is "always reserved".  Creating an identifier such as strlen() in your code, per the C standard, "always" invokes undefined behavior.  The behavior is undefined whether or not specific header files that define strlen() are included, and the behavior is undefined whether or not specific libraries are linked.
You may be able to work around issues and make your code work, but you can never really know that it will work in the future under different conditions.  That's what "undefined behavior" means - you can never know.

That make sense. thanks a lot<3

Here is a guide:
https://hero.handmade.network/forums/code-discussion/t/94-guide_-_how_to_avoid_c_c%20%20_runtime_on_windows#:~:text=So%20I%20made%20a%20guide%20how%20to%20do
https://nullprogram.com/blog/2023/02/15/#:~:text=Starting%20with%20the%20GNU%20toolchain,%20you%20have%20two#:~:text=Starting%20with%20the%20GNU%20toolchain,%20you%20have%20two
Basically, you need to pass additional flags to the compiler. Search things like /nodefaultlib  on MSDN.
PS:
Sorry, Mr. future reader when the links are broken.

Actually that's the question, I didn't find the addition flag passed to the compiler. You mention /nodefaultlib, that is the next step: linking part, during the compilation, it shouldn't link any lib.
I know the gnu toolchain can do this easily, but seems not the same for msvc toolchain :(

An answer should be self-contained, not just links out to external resources. As you note yourself those links may be broken in the future.

nodefaultlib is an msvc flag

Secondly, your code with the same compiler compiles into .obj just fine. (with a some warnings, because your code sucks: like "MarsCRT\src\MarsString.c(70) : warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary: Result")
